# Failures in Definitely Typed packages definitions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm working on a project which uses multiple packages from the definitely typed repository. But the types are working incorrectly in my project. For example, it says that:
`JSX element type 'Component<any, ComponentState> | ReactElement<any>' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.`
when I try to render a variable that is typed as `React.ComponentType.`

Also, my version of typescript finds multiple errors in the definitely typed package *.d.ts files. for example, one of its errors in the react's index.d.ts is this:
`Type 'ChangeTargetHTMLAttributes<T>' does not satisfy the constraint 'DOMAttributes<T>'. Types of property 'onChange' are incompatible.`

I'm also experiencing the same issues with multiple other type definitions such as `react-transition-group` and `gatsby`.

I'm using a workspace specific version of typescript that is locked into `v3.7.2`. And I can't find the `@types/react` package as a dependency in my package.json file but it can be found in the `node_modules/types/react` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It fixed after removing yarn.lock and re-installing node_modules without the lock